# Where does my c# solution saves its client certificates?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I managed to make a IIS website that requires a client certificate, I also got the code working, but when I send the code to other people it still uses my certificate.

Here is my code:

```
private async Task<Pas> testPas(string loc)
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
        using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { UseProxy = false, ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic }))
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://somesite.tk");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(loc).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

I think it's because the ClientCertificateOptions.Automatic retrieves the certificate and stores it somewhere in the project but i have no idea.

Even when i have another Valid Personal Certificate installed, it will stil try to choose the one I tested it with.

EDIT: Found a solution.
Really weird though, but it seems that it imports the certificate I'm using in Chrome. When i change the certificate I use in Chrome the application will use that one as well, but changing it in Console (mmc) won't work.